# Как лучше разбираться с OpenSource проектом новичку?

Tags: python, работа, opensource

Подскажите советами.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно разобраться с одним OpenSource проектом (20 000 строк кода). Документации по нему особой нет. Небольшие мануалы и не более, комментарии в коде нормальные. С командой разработчиков никаких контактов нет.

Сроки вроде не поджимают, можно спокойно работать, но и полгода я думаю мне никто не  даст на это дело. Проект написан на python, wxPython + используются Си-расширения. Я вообще C++ программист и python изучаю где-то 2 недели. Вообще как-то нужно мне всё это дело скомпоновать.

Какие можете дать советы? Как лучше всем этим заниматься? Может какие-то есть пожелания под таймменеджменту. Хотелось бы услышать в первую очередь советов от опытных программистов, чтобы не наступать на грабли. А подойти к этому делу как-то более собранным и с меньшим количеством косякой и нерационально потраченного времени.

Заранее спасибо за ответы, если будут :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тесты есть?
Если да - начни с них, это лучшая документация.

Comment: нету вроде. По крайней мере я не нашел их.

Comment: Мне как-то сложно представить себе прокект на 20к строк без единого теста. А вобще да, поддерживаю ответ - начинать проще "сверху", а потом все ниже и ниже по по структуре кода спускаться.